# Javascript doesn't work in IE8

Tags: javascript, flash, dom, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to create this html elements dynamically on the onload of my page,however;when I run it the code wont work on IE8 but okay in firefox,safari,and others.

```
 function getmovie() {
           var container = document.getElementById("container");
           if (!container)
               return;
           var object = document.createElement("object");
           object.setAttribute("width", "512");
           object.setAttribute("height", "296");
           var param1 = document.createElement("param");
           param1.setAttribute("name", "movie");
           param1.setAttribute("value", "url");
           var param2 = document.createElement("param");
           param2.setAttribute("name", "allowFullScreen");
           param2.setAttribute("value", "true");
           var embed = document.createElement("embed");
           embed.setAttribute("src", "my url");
           embed.setAttribute("type", "application/x-shockwave-flash");
           embed.setAttribute("allowFullScreen", "true");
           embed.setAttribute("width", "512");
           embed.setAttribute("height", "296");
           object.appendChild(param1);
           object.appendChild(param2);
           object.appendChild(embed);
           container.appendChild(object);
           }
```

Can anyone correct my code?

Comment: Please turn this into a "working" example that people can run, then we can help.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have a really good reason to build your Flash including DOM elements manually, consider replacing the code with a single call to a framework like [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) that does all the "dirty work" for you.

```
swfobject.embedSWF("flashmovie.swf", "container", "512", "296", "9.0.0",
    "expressInstall.swf", { allowFullScreen : true });
```

Comment: +1, definitely what you should do. SWFObject is a lot safer, than *anything* you might try,

Answer (score 1):

You can't set the `name` attribute of ANY element in IE by using `.setAttribute('name', value);`

You will need to use:

```
param1.name = 'movie';//works

param1.setAttribute("name", "movie");//will fail
```

Note: [this bug was fixed in IE8](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/08/bug-242-setattribute-doesnt-always-work.html) (as long as you are running in IE8 Standards Mode)

Answer (score 0):

Could this be the reason?

> [IE7](http://remysharp.com/2007/02/10/ie-7-breaks-getelementbyid/) breaks [getElementById](http://www.sixteensmallstones.org/ie-javascript-bugs-overriding-internet-explorers-documentgetelementbyid-to-be-w3c-compliant-exposes-an-additional-bug-in-getattributes)

---

If that is not the case, try setting the codebase and classid attributes of the object tag
object.

```
object.setAttribute("codebase", "http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/swflash.cab");
object.setAttribute("classid", "clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000");
```

Comment: The problem likely isn't the getElementById() as Firefox and Safari would choke too.