# document.createElement throwing error in IE 8. This command is not Supported ERROR

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript doesn't work in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788639/javascript-doesnt-work-in-ie8)

I have the following code

```
 var ind=1;
 try
   {
     rdo = document.createElement('<input type="radio" name="radioOptions" />');

    }
  catch(err)
  {
    rdo = document.createElement('input');                  
  }
  rdo.setAttribute('type','radio');// error
  rdo.setAttribute('name','radioOptions');
  rdo.id = 'radioOption_'+ind;
  rdo.value = ind;
```

After a thorough checkup this line is throwing error on IE 8

```
 rdo.setAttribute('type','radio')
```

and a strange fact is that when it is on the local system its not doing that. 
I am dynamically adding this radio input to the form. And the Doc type i have set to

```
 <!doctype html>
```

Any Idea what should work for all Browsers including the ASS HOLE IE

Comment: You will find the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788639/javascript-doesnt-work-in-ie8). Short: you can't set type or name in IE by setAttribute. Use object-dot-notation: rdo.type = 'radio'; rdo.name = 'radioOptions';

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not change the `type` of `input` elements in IE with `setAttribute()`. You could try with `rdo.type = 'radio'` (which should work) or (*ugh*) `innerHTML`.

Also, `document.createElement()` is used with the element's name, i.e. `input`. It is **not** like `$()` in jQuery or similar libraries.